# How to change values when a button is triggered in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I create a button in React that when triggered, change the "data" values to "data2"

```
export function Home() { 

  return (  
      <div className="instagram-container">
          {
            data.map( data =>{
              return (
                <div key={data.id} className="row"><Posts id={`${data.href}`}/></div>
              )
            })
          }      
      </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the react documentation?
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
export function Home() { 
  const data1 = [1, 2, 3], data2 = [4, 5, 6];
  const [data, setData] = useState(data1);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);

  const changeValue = () => {
     if(flag) {
        let arr = [...data2];
        setData(arr);
     }
     else {
        let arr = [...data1];
        setData(arr);
     }
     setFlag(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (  
      <div className="instagram-container">
          <button onClick={changeValue}>Change Value</button>
          {
            data.map( data =>{
              return (
                <div key={data.id} className="row"><Posts id={`${data.href}`}/></div>
              )
            })
          }      
      </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: it works if I change useState manually, but not when clicking on the button, The page remains static

Comment: Try reading more about setState function, and about state not updating issue.